# Detect beacon when in the proximity, iOS & Android application

Tags: android, ios, ibeacon, beacon

I'm building an iOS and Android application and want a user to get notified when he'll be in the proximity of a Beacon. I am looking to understand the following cases whether the user will be able to receive the notification:

1. If the application is in the background and the user has come into the proximity of a Beacon, will it allow the application to send him a local notification?
2. If the application is in the killed state and the user has come into the proximity of a Beacon, will it allow the application to send him a local notification?
3. Which Beacon will be best for my use case?

any help here will be appreciated.

Comment: For starters i think you are confused between a push notification and a local notification. Push notification is sent by the server not by the device.

Comment: Yes, I was trying to say local notification, here.

Answer (score 2):

**1. Yes**

**2. Yes**

If an application is killed, you have to make sure that on Android you run a background service that listens for beacon proximity and make sure it does not get killed by the system. On iOS side you should setup background beacon scanning with Bluetooth LE accessories usage turned on in "Compatibilities" which will not get killed by system if setup correctly.

If your Bluetooth device is NOT a Beacon and just streams some advertisement data over the air, then on Android side you should be able to setup background Bluetooth scanner, while on iOS it will not be possible to do such a thing if a Bluetooth device is not connectable (even with connectable device it will be hard).

Those services could launch local notification when beacon enters required range.

**3. Any**

---

Answers are valid if Android and iOS applications are setup correctly and Beacons are TRUE beacons and not a random Bluetooth devices that stream advertisment data.

---

Good luck :)

Comment: can you give some details on Point 2, why its Yes.

Comment: if application is killed, you have to make sure that on Android you run a background service that listens for beacon proximity and make sure that it does not get killed by system, while on iOS side you should setup background beacon scanning with bluetooth LE accessories usage turned on in "Compatibilities". If your bluetooth device is NOT a Beacon and just streams some advertisment data over the air, then on Android side you should be able to setup background bluetooth scanner, while on iOS it won't be possible to do such a thing if bluetooth device is not connectable.

Comment: Good answer.  I would add that on iOS you really must use the iBeacon format for (1) and (2) to work.  Other beacon formats will not work quickly in case (1) or at all in case (2). On Android you can use the open source Android Beacon Library to accomplish the above out of the box.

Comment: If the application does not have location access of the device, will the app still be able to discover the Beacon in the killed state and will be able to send a local notification?

Comment: @davidgyoung should know more about permissions on both platforms, I, unfortunately, do not have enough experience with beacons to point you the the right direction.

Comment: No, if location access has not been granted to the app, the app cannot detect beacons in any state on either platform.

Comment: @davidgyoung,  do we need to continuously fetch the location of the user, to get him detected when he is coming in the proximity of the Beacon?

Comment: The iOS CoreLocation beacon ranging API will give you an update every second about all beacons seen along with a (rough) distance estimate in meters and a signal strength field called RSSI.